# Alternative for Pressable in react native for web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-web

When using the React Native `Pressable` component, it doesn't work on the web. I'm using `expo` and `react-native-web`. Is there something I'm supposed to do with react-native-web to make it work on web?

If not, is there an expo or react-native-web alternative for `Pressable`? I know `Button` can work but there are issues styling it on mobile as far as I know. Also `TouchableHighlight` and `TouchableOpacity` seem to work but it doesn't have the same APIs and seems to not be as future-proof in the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablehighlight). Is `Pressable` simply not web-compatible at this point?

Currently, when I run `expo start` and run the app on the web, `Pressable` doesn't work on the web.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Pressable } from 'react-native';

export Button = (props) => {
  const { onPress } = props;
  return (
    <Pressable style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Save</Text>
    </Pressable>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressable works on the web. What error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks. New to react native and it was so plain (no cursor or styling) I didn't realize it was working, but your confirmation helped me realize it works and I just needed to style it.

Comment: Nice, I hope you enjoy working with React Native. It's a great piece of tech.